# adding a view just with static data

Tags: cakephp

I have a cake php application and 4 or 5 pages contain static pages in .php, I have also built some controllers/models and views for those pages that need to be dynamic. My question is.. Can I have a view just with static code there and call it something like

```
http://myweb.com/app/someemptycontroller/staticview/
```

Can this be done and if so how do i need to set it up in terms of model and controller..(maybe empty) i am not sure as I am a newbie in this cake php world.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP comes with a working pages controller, which can be used to serve up static pages.

Any view you place in /app/views/pages can be accessed like (say your view is hello.ctp):

```
http://myweb.com/pages/hello
```

If you don't like the pages controller showing in the URL, add a line like this to your app/config/routes.php file:

```
Router::connect('/hello', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display','hello'));
```

Now your page can be accessed by:

```
http://myweb.com/hello
```

Comment: Excellent this is great, one last question, how can i set up a default page to be my index, see.. I have http://myweb.com/app/controller/view/1 as the page I want to set up as the default like if someone types http://myweb.com thats the one where they should land...

Comment: Actually I have a small issue it says that Error: The view for PagesController::display() was not found.

Comment: For the error, make sure your names match (in the url you are trying to use and the file name), and that the file is a .ctp file.


To set up a default page, add a line in routes.php like:
`Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'your_controller', 'action' => 'your_action', 'your_optional_parameter'));`